# Comparing values in two datagridviews

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datatable

I have 2 datagridviews(dgv1 & dgv2) populated with rows with the same columns.

I want to have the row from dgv2 cycle through dgv1 and if a cell is more than that of the row in dgv2 I want to color the background of the cell to mark that it exceeded.

I did get it to work by using foreach and while, but it takes sooooo long to process. Any way I can compare cells that might be quicker. Because atm going once cell at a time scrolling through all 100 dgv1 rows and then moving to the next cell is taking a long time and I'm sure I'm being inefficient.

```
while (currentCell < (colCount + 1))  
{  
    foreach (DataGridViewRow rTestData in dgvSampleTestData.Rows)   
    {   
       //Test and change background color   
    }   
    currentCell++;    
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Compare the DataTables instead of DGV.  There are plenty of examples on Web for comparing DataTables in c#.